# Image data can not convert to float - python

Tags: python, image, plot, axes

I am trying to display an image in python and I am not 100% sure why imshow() is throwing an error.

The error trace is :
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "knn.py", line 65, in <module>
    digit_axes.imshow(paths[0],cmap = cm.Greys_r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1892, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5118, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 545, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data can not convert to float")
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

The code is as follows:

```
paths = []
paths.append('./images/image1.png')

digit_axes = main_figure.add_subplot(211)

digit_axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
digit_axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
digit_axes.set_title('Image')

digit_axes.imshow(paths[0],cmap = cm.Greys_r)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution by using imread()

```
img = imread(paths[0])
digit_axes.imshow(img,cmap = cm.Greys_r)
```